# Install a particular version of python package in a virtualenv created with reticulate

Tags: python, r, reticulate

When using `reticulate` package in order to use Python inside R, we can create a virtualenv thanks to the command `reticulate::virtualenv_create` specifying env name and the path to the python bin.

We can also add packages to the previously created environment like this:

```
  reticulate::virtualenv_create(envname = 'venv_shiny_app',
                                 python = '/usr/bin/python3')
  reticulate::virtualenv_install('venv_shiny_app',
                                 packages = c('numpy',
                                              'xlrd',
                                              'pandas',
                                              'beautifulsoup4',
                                              'joblib'))
```

Is it possible to **install a specific version of those packages**??

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can request a specific version of a package with, for example:

```
reticulate::virtualenv_install(packages = c("numpy==1.8.0"))
```