# How to upgrade a python package using reticulate?

Tags: python, r, numpy, shiny, reticulate

I am trying to launch a `shiny` app that uses a `python` script but I am getting this error:

```
Error in py_run_file_impl(file, local, convert) : 
  ImportError: this version of pandas is incompatible with numpy < 1.20.3
your numpy version is 1.20.2.
Please upgrade numpy to >= 1.20.3 to use this pandas version
```

I have run this code in the terminal to update the package:

```
pip install --force-reinstall numpy==1.20.3

Collecting numpy==1.20.3
  Using cached numpy-1.20.3-cp37-cp37m-manylinux_2_12_x86_64.manylinux2010_x86_64.whl (15.3 MB)
Installing collected packages: numpy
  Attempting uninstall: numpy
    Found existing installation: numpy 1.20.3
    Uninstalling numpy-1.20.3:
      Successfully uninstalled numpy-1.20.3
Successfully installed numpy-1.20.3
```

But I still get the same error (although I have re-started R). It seems that I have `numpy` 1.20.3 in my computer but `reticulate` is using a different version (1.20.2.)

I have also tried this from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60882638/install-a-particular-version-of-python-package-in-a-virtualenv-created-with-reti) but I didn't have any success and I am bit lost.

```
> reticulate::virtualenv_install('venv_shiny_app',
+                                packages = c('numpy' ))
Using virtual environment 'venv_shiny_app' ...
Error in if (idx != -1) version <- substring(version, 1, idx - 1) : 
  the condition has length > 1
In addition: Warning message:
In system2(python, c("-c", shQuote(command)), stdout = TRUE, stderr = TRUE) :
  running command ''/home/user/.virtualenvs/venv_shiny_app/bin/python' -c 'import sys; import pip; sys.stdout.write(pip.__version__)' 2>&1' had status 1
```

Does anybody know how to solve it?

These are the scripts that I am using:

**Shiny app (dummyRshiny.R):**

```
library(shiny)
library(reticulate)
library(DT)
library(dplyr)
library(formattable)
library(shinymanager)
library(shinyhelper) 
library(shinyWidgets) # pickerInput

source_python("/home/user/Downloads/dummyMedians.py")


ui <- fluidPage(
  fileInput('file1', 'Browse and select your variants CSV file',
            accept=c('csv', 
                     'comma-separated-values', 
                     '.csv'),
            placeholder = "No variants file provided"),

  mainPanel(
    # prepare the first output table or text for now
    
    h3("Median Levels by Sex"),
    DT::dataTableOutput('table1'),
  
  
  )
)


server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  # get the data from file
  
  getData <- reactive({
    
    # check that file2 has been provided
    # otherwise, return NULL to avoid warning messages
    # https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24647951/shiny-error-file-must-be-a-character-string-or-connection
    if(is.null(input$file1))     
      return(NULL) 
    
    inFile <- input$file1 # get the variable data from the file provided
    
    inputFilePath = inFile$datapath # get the file path for the variable database file
    
    # this needs to be a csv file with the sample numbers and the sample metadata with variables of interest
    
    myData <- read.csv(inputFilePath, sep=",") 
  
    return(myData)
  }) 
  
  # get medians
  
  getMedianLevelsDF <- reactive({
    
    if(is.null(input$file1))     
      return(NULL) 
    
    medianDF <- calculateMedianValues(getData())
    
    # unlist all the columns in the dataframe - these interfere with the column assignment of numeric types
    medianDF <- data.frame(lapply(medianDF, function(x) unlist(x)))
    
    # convert all character columns to factors for easy filtering
    medianDF <- medianDF%>%mutate_if(is.character, as.factor)
    
    return(medianDF)
    
  })
  
 
    output$table1 <- renderDataTable({
      
      datatable(
        #selected_columns_Data(),
        getMedianLevelsDF(),
        filter = list(position = 'top', clear = FALSE),
        selection = "none", #this is to avoid select rows if you click on the rows
        rownames = FALSE,
        extensions = 'Buttons',
        
        options = list(
          scrollX = TRUE,
          dom = 'Blrtip',
          buttons =
            list('copy', 'print', list(
              extend = 'collection',
              buttons = list(
                list(extend = 'csv', filename = "Counts", title = NULL),
                list(extend = 'excel', filename = "Counts", title = NULL)),
              text = 'Download'
            )),
          lengthMenu = list(c(10, 30, 50, -1),
                            c('10', '30', '50', 'All'))
        ),
        class = "display"
      )
      
    })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

**csv file that you upload in the shiny app:**

```
myData <- structure(list(sampleNumber = c("S1", "S2", "S3", "S4", "S5", 
"S6", "S7", "S8"), TSH = c(0.397, 1.2, 0.5, 1.67, 0.78, 0.5, 
1.4, 2), Sex = c("Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Female", "Female", 
"Female", "Female")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-8L))
```

**Python script (dummyMedians.py):**

```
 # for each sex, subset the data to get male and female values separately

    nSexes = 0
    
    for sampeSex in sampeSexes:

        subsetSex = dataDF.loc[(dataDF["Sex"] == sampeSex)]
        
        #print(subsetSex)

        # get the values for each sex

        sexVals = subsetSex["TSH"].tolist()

        nSex = len(sexVals) # number of samples with that sex

        # get the medians and quantiles

        TSH_25 = round(subsetSex["TSH"].quantile(q=0.25),2)
        TSH_median = round(subsetSex["TSH"].quantile(q=0.50),2)
        TSH_75 = round(subsetSex["TSH"].quantile(q=0.75),2)

        # then return a dataframe

        
        
        resultsTable = [{'Variable':'TSH',
                      'Sex':sampeSex,
                      'TSH_25':TSH_25,
                      'TSH_median':TSH_median,
                      'TSH_75':TSH_75}]
        
        
        resultsDF = pd.DataFrame(resultsTable)
        
        if nSexes < 1:
            
            finalDF = resultsDF.copy(deep=True)
            
        else:
            
            finalDF = pd.concat([resultsDF,finalDF])
            
        
        nSexes += 1
            

    return finalDF
```

Thanks very much in advance

Comment: It looks like you're installing numpy within a virtualenv. Are you setting the same virtualenv within reticulate, using `use_virtualenv()`? See https://rstudio.github.io/reticulate/reference/use_python.html

Comment: No, I cannot install `numpy` using virtualenv. I installed it from the terminal as I wrote in the post but `reticulate` doesn't recognise the new version. Therefore, I tried other things like `virtualevent` using this code: `reticulate::virtualenv_create(envname = 'venv_shiny_app', python = '/usr/bin/python3')` and `reticulate::virtualenv_install('venv_shiny_app', packages = c('numpy' ))` but it gives me the error that I wrote in the post

Comment: What I mean is: It looks like the install was successful, within the virtualenv. But reticulate has to use the same virtualenv, or it won't work. You need to set the virtualenv within R using `use_virtualenv()`.

Comment: Thanks again for your reply. 
The installation outside shiny was successful, but if I use `virtualenv_install` --> `reticulate::virtualenv_install('venv_shiny_app', packages = c('numpy' ))`, I get this error: `Error in if (idx != -1) version <- substring(version, 1, idx - 1) : the condition has length > 1 In addition: Warning message: In system2(python, c("-c", shQuote(command)), stdout = TRUE, stderr = TRUE) : running command ''/home/user/.virtualenvs/venv_shiny_app/bin/python' -c 'import sys; import pip; sys.stdout.write(pip.__version__)' 2>&1' had status 1`.

Comment: Therefore, since I am not able to install anything, I cannot use the virtualenv within R. In fact, I get this error: `Error in py_run_file_impl(file, local, convert) : ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'`. Note that I also tried `reticulate::virtualenv_install('venv_shiny_app', packages = c('pandas' ))` but I get the same error as before.